# C++ manipulating Raw Data of a struct

Tags: c++, memory

I have a simple struct that looks like this:

```
struct Object 
{
    int x_;
    double y_;
};
```

I am trying to manipulate the raw data of an Object, this is what I've done:

```
int main()
{
    Object my_object;
    unsigned char* raw_data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&my_object);

    int x = 10;
    memcpy(raw_data, &x, sizeof(x));
    raw_data += sizeof(x);

    double y = 20.1;
    memcpy(raw_data, &y, sizeof(y));


    Object* my_object_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Object *>(raw_data);


    std::cout << *(my_object_ptr).x << std::endl;    //prints 20       (expected 10)
    std::cout << *(my_object_ptr).y << std::endl;    //prints Rubbish  (expected 20.1)
}
```

I was expecting that above code will work,,,

What is the real problem? Is this even possible?

Comment: hint: how do you think memcpy knowns where is `x_` and where is `y_` ?

Comment: @Arkadiy I thought raw_data+=4 would move the position to the y_'s address

Comment: Probably an alignment issue .. try packing the fields together like this:  `struct Object { .. } __attribute__((__packed__));`

Comment: Sorry - missed it. You are right.

Comment: @eduffy I've never seen that before.. Visual studio is saying identifier "packed" is undefined :(  Do I need to include anything to the file?

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx

Comment: Show your actual code. This code will not print anything. It will not even compile.

Comment: This is an abuse of the language, I'm amazed you haven't shot yourself in the foot.  The `memcpy` is slower than plain old assignment.  For copying objects, let the compiler do this; worry about other higher level logic and data structures.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I obviously know plain old assignment is way easier, but there's a reason why I'm doing all that and I'm simply asking a question. I'm amazed you haven't shot yourself in the head

Comment: @user3878106, "The C++ language allows one to shoot themselves in the foot.", referring to how pointer usage can be abused to cause anything to happen, often termed as *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). There were a few more problems too, most importantly you modified `raw_data` pointer, and then cast the modified value back to `Object*` pointer, resulting in Undefined Behavior. I chose to remove the `raw_data` modification (alternative would have been to not cast it back, but to just inspect `my_object` directly). Here's a fixed code for you, with explanation in comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // for memcpy
#include <cstddef> // for offsetof macro

struct Object 
{
    int x_;
    double y_;
};

int main()
{
    Object my_object;
    unsigned char* raw_data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&my_object);

    int x = 10;
    // 1st memcpy fixed to calculate offset of x_ (even though it is probably 0)
    memcpy(raw_data + offsetof(Object, x_), &x, sizeof(x));
    //raw_data += offsetof(Object, y_); // if used, add offset of y_ instead of sizeof x

    double y = 20.1;
    // 2nd memcpy fixed to calculate offset of y_ (offset could be 4 or 8, depends on packing, sizeof int, etc)
    memcpy(raw_data + offsetof(Object, y_), &y, sizeof(y));

    // cast back to Object* pointer
    Object* my_object_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Object *>(raw_data);


    std::cout << my_object_ptr->x_ << std::endl;    //prints 10
    std::cout << my_object_ptr->y_ << std::endl;    //prints 20.1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a structure padding issue. If you had `double y_` as the first member, you'd probably have seen what you expected. The compiler will pad the structure with extra bytes to make the alignment correct in case the struct is used in an array. Try

```
#pragma pack(4)
```

before your struct definition.

The `#pragma pack` reference for Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx Your struct is packed to 8 bytes by default, so there's a 4 byte pad between `x_` and `y_`.

Read http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ to really understand what's going on.

Comment: You can set the pack to 1 too. What is sizeof(int) for you?

Comment: @RobK Actually pack(1) solved the problem!! However, is this safe? Wouldn't getting rid of alignment cause error or problem in some systems?

Comment: It's not dangerous, it just makes memory access less efficient. Did you read the 2nd link I provided? That explains what's happening and why, and why you don't want to use `pack()` except in very specific contexts. The general rule is bigger members first when ordering struct members, to make the most efficient use of memory, but even then, only worry about that when you have ***very*** large amounts of data. 

You should **NOT** be doing what you've done in this question in production code, and certainly not if you don't understand why `pack(1)` got you the behavior you expected.